# Title for a person who studies or compiles adages?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I would like to know  if there is a word to describe a person who studies and/or compiles adages in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Adage collector*** seems like a good fit.

Example: Thomas Fuller (24 June 1654 – 17 September 1734) was an English physician, writer and **adage collector**. ([Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Thomas_Fuller_(writer)))